# Eclipse fix same error in many files

Tags: eclipse

I recently imported a large number of source files into an eclipse project. Unfortunately they all have the wrong package declaration. Is there a way to fix errors en masse across all of the files (1 error per file)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Source / Refactor / Rename (or something similar, I don't have it in front of me right now) in the editor context menu.